# Symbols not showing for external dependency

Tags: android, google-fabric

We are unsuccessfully trying to show symbols on native crashes for an external dependency.

We have an Android library module that builds the native libraries.

We have a separate fake Android application module as suggested by https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/ndk.html#uploading-symbols-for-external-dependencies that contains the Fabric plugin and symbols upload configuration. Using this `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "<REDACTED>"
        // no need to specify versionCode or versionName
    }
}

crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    // as plugin not applied to actual application/library module set paths manually
    androidNdkOut '../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/'
    androidNdkLibsOut '../build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/'
    manifestPath 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
}
```

The cSYM files are created and uploaded successfully. Yet, stack traces continue to have (missing) symbols.

How does Crashlytics know which symbols to use, is there info somewhere if uploaded symbols don't match? Does it always use the latest one uploaded or is there some versioning that might break things here?

Comment: Have you tried to run `gradlew crashlyticsUploadSymbolsDebug` with `--stacktrace` option? Does it report any issues? I'm experiencing the same issue, but in my case it seems like no symbols uploaded

Comment: According to logs symbols upload works. Talking to support about this now, hopefully they can help. Check the crashlytics.log file on your system for issues (in your user profile see `.crashlytics\com.crashlytics.tools\crashlytics.log`).
Edit: I have the suspicion that separate projects are no longer supported, despite the docs saying they are.